# Symfony 2 search form renders an unwanted search field. Can I disable this behaviour?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, search, render

**Edit**: This question refers to **Symfony 2.7**, for **Symfony 2.8+** see Ogi's answer below.

The `require` section in my `composer.json` looks like this:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
    "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",

    "braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle": "~2.0",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "3.2.*",
    "jquery/jquery": "1.11.*",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "~1.1@dev"
},
```

**NOTE:** The last four packages are added on top of Symfony2 standard edition.

Following the [Symfony 2 Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) docs chapter, I'm trying to create a search form. So, I have created an entity class:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class SearchQuery
{
/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Type(type="string", message="form.search.query.validation.type")
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min = 3,
     *      max = 50,
     *      minMessage = "form.search.query.validation.min",
     *      maxMessage = "form.search.query.validation.max"
     * )
     */
    protected $query;

    public function __construct($query = '')
    {
        $this->setQuery($query);
    }

    public function getQuery()
    {
        return $this->query;
    }

    public function setQuery($query)
    {
        $this->query = $query;
    }
}
```

And a form type class:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use 
    Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface,    
    Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType,
    Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface
;

class SearchType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('query', 'text', array(
                'label' => '',
                'attr' => array(

                ),
            ))
            ->add('save', 'submit', array(
                'label' => '',
            ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\SearchQuery',
            'attr' => array(
                'id' => 'search-form'
            )
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'search';
    }
}
```

The rendered output:

```
<form name="search" method="post" action="/app_dev.php/search" id="search-form" role="form">

    <input type="search" id="search" name="search" required="required" class="form-control" value="">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label required" for="search_query">Query</label>
        <input type="text" id="search_query" name="search[query]" required="required" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" id="search_save" name="search[save]" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="search__token" name="search[_token]" class="form-control" value="5f0e9c4a9d4e251fc62e25686cf810eaa0ff4331">
</form>
```

The problem is that something between Symfony 2 Forms, BraincraftedBootstrapBundle and Twig is trying to play smart and adds this unwanted field:

```
<input type="search" id="search" name="search" required="required" class="form-control" value="">
```

I've noticed that this happens only if the `SearchType::getName()` method returns `'search'`. If I change this to something like:

```
class SearchType extends AbstractType
{

    [...]

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'search_foo';
    }

    [...]

}
```

everything works as expected, the rendered output is:

```
<form name="search_foo" method="post" action="/app_dev.php/cautare" id="search-form" role="form">
    <div id="search_foo">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label required" for="search_foo_query">Query</label>
            <input type="text" id="search_foo_query" name="search_foo[query]" required="required" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" id="search_foo_save" name="search_foo[save]" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="search_foo__token" name="search_foo[_token]" class="form-control" value="68ee88cb3adef211b993806029ba3fa989322c80">
    </div>
</form>
```

Of course, I can change the name to something else and move on, but it's like a nail being hammered in my head to do so without understanding what's really happening behind the curtains.

I've even tried to set the [field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types.html) to `search` instead of `text` hoping that if it sees that there is a search field would leave me alone and won't try to guess what my intentions are, but no, it still prints the unwanted field.

Comment: I run into the same problem on Symfony 2.8 and 3.0. Very weird behavior. Maybe someone in the community will have some time to dig it https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/16899

Answer (score 1):

You might have seen or not the issue created by @aistis in its comment.

I see from your `composer.json` file that you seems to use symfony 2.3. So this error is strange because it should only happens since 2.8...

Anyway, the solution is pretty straightforward, but not obvious: you should implement the `getBlockPrefix` method in your form type:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

// [...]

class SearchType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // [...]
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_search'
    }
}
```

**To keep it short:** This is explained by the latest changes in the Symfony Form component, getting rid of the form aliases and `getName()` method.
A form type is now identified by its fully-qualified-class-name.
When a form is rendered, it'll compute the form name from the FQCN, by only keeping the lowercased & snake cased class name minus `Type`. Then it'll use this computed name to render the form theme block matching this name.

As a drawback, however, naming a form type identical to an existing one will lead to unexpected behaviors like you experienced.
**Good news are that you can override the way the form theme name is computed by overriding the `getBlockPrefix` method in your form type.** Thus, the solution above.

P.S: If you're really using Symfony 2.8+, you should get rid of the `setDefaultOptions` method deprecated in 2.7, in favor of the new `configureOptions` one: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/UPGRADE-2.7.md#form

Also see the list of deprecations and upgrade paths for the Symfony Form component in 2.8 here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/UPGRADE-2.8.md#form

Comment: Thanks for your documented answer! My question is 1 yo, way before Symfony 2.8 was released. I don't know how is this implemented in 2.8+, but I'm working on a project with 2.7 right now and I can't get rid of the `getName()` method since it's present in `FormTypeInterface` implemented by `AbstractType`. Also, there is no `getBlockPrefix()` method. Sorry, but I can't mark your answer as accepted, although it's presence here is good for those who are looking for 2.8+.